# OLS under Mean Independence

Tags: probability, statistics

> Assume mean independence of the error term. Show that the OLS estimator is unbiased. Hint: use the Law of Iterated Expectations

I am not quite sure if I understood the concept of 'mean independence'. So we have that $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon \mid X]=0$. My proof would be as follows:

$$\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$$$=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+\varepsilon )$$
$$=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon $$
$$=\beta+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon$$

$$\implies\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}]=\beta+\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon]$$
$$=\beta+\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T]\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon]$$
$$=\beta$$

My problem is whether I can write $\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon]=\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T]\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon]$. My intuition says yes, because mean independence implies zero covariance and hence we can write the expectation as a product. However, I haven't used the LIE. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

$$\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\varepsilon \mid X]] = \mathbb E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\mathbb E[\varepsilon \mid X]] = 0$$

we used the law of iterated expectation and the fact that $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is measurable wrt to $\sigma(X)$ (so we can bring it outside the conditional expectation)