# Proof that least squares estimators are unbiased under gauss-markov assumptions

Tags: statistics, expected-value, regression, least-squares

I saw two different derivations of $E[\hat{\beta}] = \beta$, and they don't appear to be equivalent to me.

Method 1 (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5kjKqkCvHc).

Method 2 (from https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/Gauss-Markov-theorem#hid2, under "OLS is linear and unbiased", click on the "Proof").

The latter method first computes $E[\hat{\beta}|X] = \beta$, and then use the law of iterated expectations to obtain $E[\hat{\beta}] = \beta$. The former directly computes this without conditioning on $X$. Are these 2 different ways to arrive at the same answer, or is one of the methods arriving at the right answer using incorrect logic?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the latter uses $E[\epsilon |X] = 0$ whereas the former uses $E[\epsilon] = 0$. Why do we need to condition on $X$ in the former case? That doesn't seem to be an assumption made by the gauss-markov theorem.

Comment: When $X$ is taken to be random we condition on $X$ otherwise we don't. So the proof depends on your model assumptions.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Oh I see. If $X$ is fixed, then is $E[X] = X$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I listened to the youtube video a bit more closely. Starting at 2:20, he states that $\epsilon$ (he uses the symbol $u$ is independent of the $X$ terms, and that apparently this allows us to write $E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon] = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T E[\epsilon] $. I don't think this is sufficient? If they are independent, then we can write $E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon] = E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T] E[\epsilon] $. The expectation can't be dropped on the $X$ terms until we know they're constant/fixed.

Comment: If $X$ is fixed/constant, then obviously $E[X]=X$. When someone writes $E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon] = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T E[\epsilon]$, it is assumed $X$ is fixed. If $X$ is random, use the law of iterated expectation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866323/321264 (this is just the StatLect proof). I hope this clears things up because I don't understand what you are really asking.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467092/119261.